# Storage provisioning for Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, storage

I need help with my Microsft SQL Server file setup!

I have a TEST Microsoft SQL Server with 3 RAID1 (SSDs):

```
C: (240 GB)  - O/S installed
L: (460 GB)
M: (900 GB)
```

I have a PROD Microssoft SQL Server with 4 RAID1 (SSDs):

```
C: (240 GB) - O/S installed
L: (900 GB)
M: (900 GB)
T: (240 GB)
```

What is the best way to spread the SQL files for Test and Prod Servers?

Answer (score 2):

A back-of-the envelope "guess" would be to put the log files on one drive, the data files on another drive, and in the case of prod, put the tempdb files on a third drive.  You should also consider a location for SQL Server backup files that is *not* on the same drive subsystem as either your data or log files; preferably an off-machine location.

Having said that, you've provided too little data for us to really help you decide on the highest performance setup.